# Why would a map lost the coordinate system when I use it in ArcGis?

Tags: coordinate-system, import, autocad

I have a file in AutoCad with ETRS89 coordinates, and when I use the same map in ArcGIS it loses coordinates. With other files do not happen.

Comment: When you say you use the same 'map' can you be more specific please.  Do you mean you export data from AutoCAD (and if so in what format) or do you import identical datasets into AutoCAD and ArcGIS?  Are the data vector or raster?

Comment: The data is Vector and I use the "add data" command to import the data from AutoCad (dwg) to ArcGis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of ArcGIS  and Autocad are you using?

This is esri's help page for 10.1

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00100000002r000000

but you need to make sure ArcMap is a newer version then the Autocad Version you are using or save the dwg file as either 2004 or 2007 version file. ie you can't open Autocad 2011 files in  ArcMap 9.2. The other idea to try is to go to the dwg file through ArcCatalog and assign coordinates to the file using ArcCatalog before importing it Autocad.

Comment: Thank you Banger. I already assigned coordinates in the ArcCatalog. I'll try the Esri's help page. Thank you again!

Comment: this is an older post on dxf files

Comment: http://www.aubreyrhea.net/gis/index.php/2009/09/defining-the-projection-of-autocad-dxf-files/